# ajaxStart, ajaxStop only firing correctly in firefox, not chrome or ie

Tags: jquery, ajax

The code below executes fine in Firefox (i.e. the div with class="ajax-loader" shows and hides with the start and stop events respectively), but for some reason, doesn't in IE or Chrome.  (Note, using jquery version 2.2)

```
$(document).ajaxStart(
    function () {
        $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "visible");
    }
).ajaxStop(
    function () {
        $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
);
```

any ideas?

**Update**
Ok, it appears the events do fire in IE and Chrome.  I just temporarily disabled the code within the .ajaxStop segment.  The difference is that Firefox displays the loading element instantaneously whereas in Chrome and IE the .ajaxStart event does not appear to be being fired until the ajax call comes back.

Comment: my answer is helpful to you??

Comment: I hope you weren't waiting by the computer for me to try it Chirag?  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you need to try like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click").on('click', function() {
    $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "visible");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'yourURL',
      success:function(){
        $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.ajax-loader{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='click'>Click</button>
<div class="ajax-loader">Loading</div>
```

Try with defining this as per [ajaxstart doc](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

```
$.ajaxSetup({'global':true});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution.This solution is work for me.

```
$(document).on({
            ajaxStart: function () {
                $('.ajax-loader').removeClass("hide");
            },
            ajaxStop: function () {
                 $('.ajax-loader').addClass("hide");
            }
        });
```

> CSS class

```
.hide{
   display:none;
}
```

Hope this solution is work for you. Let me know if you need further help.